# I can't "go get" a dependency from github

Tags: go, github-for-windows

I made a golang app on my machine that uses cron. On my machine, I

"go get github.com/robfig/cron"

to download and install dependency then in my app I

"import cron "github.com/rk/go-cron""

the app works fine and runs the way I want. I then upload it to the server where it's supposed to run and try to "go get github.com/robfig/cron" as I did on my machine, but then it gave me this

[image]

I downloaded and installed github but still the same result. I'm guessing the problem is with github on my server machine

I am new to golang and andy kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to install is `git`. It is the version control system (VCS) used by GitHub.
The native GitHub application does not provide the command line tools used by Go.

Git can be found and downloaded at http://git-scm.com/downloads

Once installed, make sure you have the path to the Git cmd folder in your %PATH% environment variable.
You can check this by running the command: `echo %PATH%`

On a Windows installation, you might find it located here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I guess I meant git instead of github. Still the same though.

Comment: Can Windows find the git.exe file then? Try typing `where git` to make sure. Otherwise it is about adding Git to %PATH% as I wrote in an edit to the answer.